# Model Selection in Statistics

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling, model-selection, feature-selection

I have been told not to look at significance level, or not to use forward/backward selection using BIC/AIC for model selection.

Let's say, I have 100 survey data with 11 variables and I want to see the relation of one of those variables with the rest. I wanted to regress the dependent variable on 10 explanatory variable. But, as I was suggested not to trust significance levels, on what basis do I select a model and confirm that it is indeed the best?

Comment: This might be a duplicate question since it is very generic and other people must have asked it before. However, I was not able to find an exact duplicate quickly. Anyway, you will certainly learn a lot of useful ideas by checking out the already-answered questions with the tag `feature-selection` [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-selection?sort=votes&pageSize=30) (you can sort them by criteria "newest", "frequent", "votes", "active", "unanswered").

Comment: There are numerous posts on site on model selection which make important points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you should not use significance, or strategies that are based on it (e.g., forward or backward selection, etc.).

The bigger question is why do you need to select a model at all?  If you want to test a hypothesis about a particular variable, you can do that without any meaningful model selection.  If you want to test a variable while controlling for certain other variables, you can do that too.  You don't need to 'select' a model with certain covariates, just include the variables you were concerned about a-priori.

On the other hand, if you want to build a model that you will use to make predictions in the future, it is better to focus on what data you will have in the future.  In the predictive context, if you really need to select a model, [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) is likely to be your best bet.

Comment: I agree with gung but cross-validation dumps some of data before estimating model parameters so it depends on cases. In particular I am reading "Model Selection Indices for Polytomous Items"(T. Kang et al., 2009) and there AIC and BIC outperformed CVLL and DIC.

Comment: It is not correct to say cross-validation would select a model in a good way without providing a reference that shows exactly this. Cross-validation has been shown to work well with LASSO for prediction problems with Gaussian data, see, e.g., [1]. But, the "best model" can be found only if you know what you are searching for. Best in terms of achieving min squared errors, absolute errors, best in terms of prediction, etc. Ref:
[1] Chetverikov, D., Liao, Z., & Chernozhukov, V. (2021). On cross-validated lasso in high dimensions. Annals of Statistics, 49 (3), 1300-1317.

Comment: @JonasStriaukas, I did specify prediction. CV can be used with LASSO, but also with ridge regression, elastic net (both) or other methods.  'Best' can be in terms of minimizing squared errors, absolute errors, or other metrics as well.

Comment: Correct, I thought adding some details would be beneficial. Also, the comment on what is the 'best' model refers more to the initial question, again adding more to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Model selection is one of the most difficult task in statistics. There is no silver bullet in finding the best model.

You have to create many models - candidates for champion model.

With your data it should be relatively easy (but no so much instances - a rule of thumb to estimate one variable you need about 30 instances) - in first step create one big model, then few others with backward/forward/stepwise selection and compare them. Both in terms of statistics (AIC, BIC, ...) and interpretation of results.

Don't forget to create transformed variables - thay may improve your model.